# Conversão de tipos SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho o seguinte `SELECT` no SQL Server:

```
SELECT  
    th.CidadeCod,
    th.ContratoCod,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), ( SUM(th.PlacasLidas)/SUM(th.Trafego) ) * 100) AS [IndiceOCR]
FROM 
    controle.TrafegoFaixaHora th 
INNER JOIN ssis.Contratos c ON th.ContratoCod = c.ContratoCod AND th.CidadeCod = c.CidadeCod
INNER JOIN controle.Equipamentos e ON th.ContratoCod = e.ContratoCod AND th.CidadeCod = e.CidadeCod
WHERE 
    c.FlagAtivo = 1 AND e.FlagOcr = 1
GROUP BY 
    th.CidadeCod,
    th.ContratoCod
```

Porém o erro é retornado:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

O que devo fazer ?

Comment: está retornando um valor maior que 5 (incluindo a parte inteira e dígitos decimais) no cálculo que você está tentando converter. Veja o resultado de `( SUM(th.PlacasLidas)/SUM(th.Trafego) ) * 100`. Retorne isso sem o `convert` para ver o tamanho do valor, dai você ajusta o tamanho do `decimal` corretamente

Comment: os campo PlacasLidas e Trafego são de que tipo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT  
        th.CidadeCod
        ,th.ContratoCod
        ,SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT,th.Trafego)) AS [trafego]
        ,SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT,th.PlacasLidas)) AS [placaslidas]
        ,( 
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), 
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,5), SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT,th.PlacasLidas))) / 
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,5), SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT,th.Trafego))) 
        *100 )) AS [IndiceOCR]
FROM controle.TrafegoData th 
INNER JOIN ssis.Contratos c ON th.ContratoCod = c.ContratoCod AND th.CidadeCod = c.CidadeCod
INNER JOIN controle.Equipamentos e ON th.ContratoCod = e.ContratoCod AND th.CidadeCod = e.CidadeCod

WHERE 
    th.Data BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-14,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY,-8,GETDATE())
    AND c.FlagAtivo = 1 
    AND e.FlagOcr = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Altere

```
 CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), ( SUM(th.PlacasLidas)/SUM(th.Trafego) ) * 100) AS [IndiceOCR]
```

para algo assim:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), ( SUM(th.PlacasLidas)/SUM(th.Trafego) ) * 100) AS [IndiceOCR]
```

Comment: não deu certo desse jeito

Comment: Ainda deu o mesmo erro?

Comment: sim. mesmo erro

Comment: Altere para DECIMAL( 15, 5 ) . por exemplo.

Comment: Mesmo erro. Coloquei DECIMAL (15,15) e também não foi

Comment: Que numeros vem em SUM( th.PlacasLidas ) e em  SUM( th.Trafego ) ?

Comment: th.Trafego = 4244244928 e th.PlacasLidas = 873313340. Fiz a divisão da seguinte maneira agora: ,( SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT,th.PlacasLidas)) / SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT,th.Trafego)) ) * 100 AS [IndiceOCR] , porém foi retornado 0

Comment: Fiz com DECIMAL( 15, 10 ) com esses números e funcionou. Retornou:  485.9933695700